# Paypal integration Bad request / Order could not be captured

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I am trying to implement paypal with credit/Debit card in react.js
Here, I am using references for this : [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@bolajifemi28/how-to-add-paypal-checkout-to-your-react-app-37d44c58a896)

& Here is my code references for paypal button:

```
 createOrder = (data, actions) => {
    // console.log('action',actions.order);
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          description: +"Mercedes G-Wagon",         
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: 200,
            // intent: 'capture',
          },
        },
      ],     
    });
  };

  onApprove = (data, actions) => {
    actions.order.capture().then(details => {
      const paymentData = {
        payerID: data.payerID,
        orderID: data.orderID
      };
      console.log("Payment Approved: ", paymentData);
    });
  };
```

Here is the code of paypal button:

```
 <PayPalButton
              createOrder={(data, actions) => this.createOrder(data, actions)}
              onApprove={(data, actions) => this.onApprove(data, actions)}
            />
```

Also I added PAYPAL SDK Link

```
src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Ae-iRhlCvBlx2WS-YACHU3MAMbbDPTj9Cp-ynyMFi2qautDvNMynnDn1mG3qgqyeiCD6IAFG0MPHfBxj
"
```

I tried with make payment using credit/Debit card and choose India in county drop-down  But everytime I got the same error that **"Order could not be captured"**

How I can resolve this error ??